# Using dispatch in class based component give error of invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I am new to `react-redux`. I have this code, I am using `react`, `redux` and `TypeScript`.
In this code using class based component, and i want to use dispatch to call action for increment the value of `counter`, butut that gives me the following error.

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

Here is my class based component code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { Dispatch } from 'redux';
import { increment, decrement } from '../actions/counterAction';

interface IHome {
    counter: 0
}

class Home extends React.Component<IHome> {
    render() {
        const dispatch = useDispatch();

        return (
            <div>
                This is the home page {this.props.counter}
                <button onClick={()=>dispatch(increment)}>+</button>
                <button>-</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: IHome) => {
    return {
        counter: state.counter
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    return {
        increment: () => dispatch(increment()),
        decrement: () => dispatch(decrement())
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

I don't know where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `useDispatch()` hook can only be used in functional components.

Since you have already connected your component, you have already passed the redux actions (`decrement`, and `increment`) to your component via the `props`.

However, you will need to fix your component's props interface, as currently, TypeScript thinks that the only valid prop is `counter`.

```
interface StoreProps {
  counter: number
}

interface DispatchProps {
  increment: () => void;
  decrement: () => void;
}

type IHome = DispatchProps & StoreProps;

class Home extends React.Component<IHome> {
    render() {
        const { counter, increment, decrement } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                This is the home page {counter}
                <button onClick={()=>increment()}>+</button>
                <button>-</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok it works, but you need to remove 'const dispatch' from render function. otherwise this will give the same.

Answer (score 1):

Home is a class component. You have to change it to function component if you want to use hooks in it. In this case you can get rid of the connect and map... function calls and use the useStore hook for the store.

```
export default const Home: React.FC<IHome> = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const store = useStore()

  return (
      <div>
          This is the home page {store.getState().counter}
          <button onClick={() => dispatch(increment())}>+</button>
          <button>-</button>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I used once with the const and it work but i don't want to pass each state like this '({counter})', which is not good, so i used mapStateToProps and then connect then together, 
There must be another way to use mapDispatchToProps function in my class component.

Comment: Yes @peter, but I want to use class component not const, if it was not class component then this answer is right which I already know